# Скопировать файл из одной папки в другую

Tags: java, файлы

Требуется скопировать файл из одной папки в другую. Сделать это было решено через функцию "fileCopy()". Но он всё время подчёркнут красным и не распознаётся как функция.

Код:

```
String way = scn.next();

userBookWay = new File(way);

FileInputStream fis = new 

FileInputStream(userBookWay);

FileOutputStream fis1 = new 

FileOutputStream(userBookFile);

fileCopy(fis, fis1);
```

Все поля и объекты объявлены. Но весь код скинуть не могу.

Comment: В Java нет функций.

Comment: Вы смысле? Есть методы?

Comment: Не помогло FileUtils.copyFile(fis, fis1); "FileUtils" выделен красным

Comment: @Kotarduinshika да, есть только методы. А методы всегда относятся к какому-то классу. Из какого класса метод `fileCopy`?

Comment: Класс File, для работы с файлами или каталогами.

Comment: Может `userBookWay.copyFile()` тогда?

Comment: Возможно и так, только copyFile - красное. Вообще есть такой метод сopyFile?

Comment: @Kotarduinshika в классе [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) нет такого метода.

Comment: Посмотрел, блин, первую ссылку в гугле... Может подскажете какой метод используется для копирования файла?

Comment: `fileCopy`, в своем первом комментарии я писал

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Files.copy(Paths.get("source.txt"), Paths.get("copy.txt"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если это статический метод в другом классе, то надо использовать статический вызов с использованием названия класса через точку.

```
File.fileCopy(fis, fis1);
```

Можно также использовать статический импорт методов из другого класса. Для этого надо использовать `import static`.

Comment: Мы наверное друг-друга не до поняли. Это вызывается так: import java.io.File;

Comment: Я совсем запутался. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Ничего из этого не помогло.